break DAG lineage in DLT
I have an iterative transformation applied to a dataframe, it used to take a long time and having done lots of research online, it appears the issue was due to the DAG from growing exponentially.  To fix this I cme across a solution which was to break the lineage by converting the dataframe to RDD and then back to pyspark again after each transformation in a loop.
This works wonders when applied to a normal table, but now I'm using DLT and I'm getting this error:
Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();

Is there any way to resolve this?

Please add more details of you dlt pipeline code, DAG screenshot etc. And expected output.

The ERROR indicates that the foreachBatch operation is not recognized by Databricks Live Tables (DLT).

Queries with streaming sources must be executed with
writeStream.start();

The foreachBatch operation is not supported in Databricks Live Tables (DLT) for streaming queries.
To work around this limitation, you can take the following approach:
Instead of writing directly to the target table (DLT )within the foreachBatch operation, write the intermediate results to a temporary table.
After processing each micro-batch, store the results in this temporary table.
Finally, use a separate job or process to periodically merge the data from the temporary table into your target table.
Reference: DLT fails with Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();
